# How to filter posts by category

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I tried to filter posts by category but it's not working on frontend

I want when a user clicks on a particular category to get posts in that category

**this is my backend (NODEJS)**

```
exports.getMovies = async (req, res) => {
    const { pageNo = 0, limit = 10 } = req.query;
    // filter category
    let filter = {};
    if (req.query.categories) {
    filter = { category: req.query.categories.split(",") };
    }

    const movies = await Movie.find(filter)
    .populate("category comments")
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .skip(parseInt(pageNo) * parseInt(limit))
    .limit(parseInt(limit));

    const results = movies.map((movie) => ({
    id: movie._id,
    title: movie.title,
    poster: movie.poster?.url,
    responsivePosters: movie.poster?.responsive,
    category: movie.category,
    comments: movie.comments,
    genres: movie.genres,
    status: movie.status,
    }));

    res.json({ movies: results });
};
```

**The front end API**

```
export const getMovies = async (pageNo, limit, filter) => {
    const token = getToken();
    try {
    const { data } = await client(
        `/movie/movies?pageNo=${pageNo}&limit=${limit}&filter=${filter}`,
        {
        headers: {
            authorization: "Bearer " + token,
            "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        }
    );
    return data;
    } catch (error) {
    return catchError(error);
    }
};
```

**The front end CATEGORY COMPONENT**

I want the user to filter the post by category by clicking on the category

```
export default function AllCategory() {
    const [allCategories, setAllCategories] = useState([]);

    const fetchCategories = async () => {
    const res = await getCategoryForUsers();

    setAllCategories(res);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategories();
    }, []);
    return (
    <div className=''>
        <ul className=' space-x-4 '>
        {allCategories.map((c, index) => {
            return <li key={index}>{c.title}</li>;
        })}
        </ul>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ``` as that is not how to post code here.

You'll want to use a filter first in another function

```
const [selectedCategories, setCurrentlySelectedCategories] = useState([]);

const handleSelectCategory = (category) => {
   const currentlySelected = allCategories.filter((item) => item.category == category);
   setCurrentlySelectedCategories(currentlySelected);
}
```

Now just call map on the selectedCategories

Comment: where is the currentlySelected  coming from?

Comment: @KelvinHenry sorry I forgot to define it as a new variable

Comment: its Empty array [] on the console

**CODE**


  const [selectedCategories, setCurrentlySelectedCategories] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectCategory = (category) => {
    const currentlySelected = allCategories.filter(
      (item) => item.category == category
    );
    setCurrentlySelectedCategories(currentlySelected);
  };
{selectedCategories.map((c, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index}>
              <p
                onClick={() => handleSelectCategory()}
              >
                {c.title}
              </p>